# How safe is Myanmar likely to be for tourists in early 2023?

Tags: safety, event-based-effects, myanmar

I'd like to make tourism there in a few months but, at least some months ago the country seemed to be in the middle of several crises.
There seemed to be some armed conflicts, an important economic crisis, the country being run by the military (which is not necessarily bad, but I believe it's more likely to cause more armed conflict), Rohinya crisis...

Is it too unstable for tourists? Or are these localized things and, as long as some areas are avoided, it's mostly safe for tourists?

Comment: The US DoS has a **Do Not Travel** [advisory](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/traveladvisories/burma-travel-advisory.html) so I wouldn't go there personally

Comment: The current situation is likely to change, so most answers are likely only going to be useful for a limited amount of time. I think another question might have the answers for you, which is similar to @NicolasFormichella commented:
[How to figure if it is safe to travel to the area I am interested in?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59874/how-to-figure-if-it-is-safe-to-travel-to-the-area-i-am-interested-in)